# (3/3) QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'userimage' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel

I got this error while registering the users with Image upload facility.
I've given all the details correctly but unable to figure out whats happening.
Please look unto this.... thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD2Ct.png)

Here is the controller :

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'userimage' => 'required|image'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $path = Storage::putFile('userimages',$data['userimage']);
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'userimage' => $path,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Model is ::

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'user_image',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function todo()
    {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Todo');
    }
}
```

and in the filesystems.php file

```html
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'public'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Cloud Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Many applications store files both locally and in the cloud. For this
    | reason, you may specify a default "cloud" driver here. This driver
    | will be bound as the Cloud disk implementation in the container.
    |
    */

    'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "s3", "rackspace"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: make `userimage` `nullable` in your migration file

Comment: you have a required field for image in the validation and also you are passing user image in the create function, so if you dont upload an image it will throw and error,

Answer (score 3):

Code for `User` model : Here you have given `user_image` and in your controller `userimage`, so the value of `user_image` is null. That's why you are getting error. Change variable name from controller to `user_image` and make `nullable` in database

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'user_image',
];
```